# Raku operator for 2's complement arithmetic?

Tags: raku

I sometimes use this:

```
$ perl -e "printf \"%d\", ((~18446744073709551592)+1)"
24
```

I can't seem to do it with Raku. The best I could get is:

```
$ raku -e "say +^18446744073709551592"
-18446744073709551593
```

So: how can I make Raku give me the same answer as Perl ?

Comment: Perltrap says that in Perl, " '`~`' is the one's complement operator, as in C." See: https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap

Comment: yes, just flip bits ... that's the reason for the `+1`  ... 

in fact I'm much more of a C and C++ guy than Perl, that's the reason I'm comfortable with `~`

Comment: The closest I get to your answer of `24` is converting to base(8). But this code: `~$ raku -e 'put +^(18446744073709551592.base(8).comb + 1)'` returns `-24` not `24`.  Let me know if that's useful (or not) and if you want me to post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks, but I'll wait some more :) ... I can't believe there isn't a simpler way to do it ... because, it's just simple 2's complement arithmetic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gotta go with (my variant¹ of) Liz's custom op (in her comment below).

```
sub prefix:<²^>(uint $a) { (+^ $a) + 1 }

say ²^ 18446744073709551592; # 24
```

My original "semi-educated wild guess"² that turned out to be acceptable to @zentrunix and the basis for Liz's op:

```
say (+^ my uint $ = 18446744073709551592) + 1; # 24
```

\o/ It works!³

## Footnotes

¹ I flipped the two character op because I wanted to follow the `+^` form, have it sub-vocalize as "two's complement", and avoid it looking like `^2`.

² One line of thinking was about the particular integer. I saw that `18446744073709551592` is close to `2**64`. Another was that integers are limited precision in Perl unless you do something to make them otherwise, whereas in Raku they are arbitrary precision unless you do something to make them otherwise. A third line of thinking came from reading the doc for [prefix `+^`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/+$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT#(Operators)_prefix_+%5E) which says "converts the number to binary using as many bytes as needed" which I interpreted as meaning that the representation is somehow important. Hmm. What if I try an `int` variable? Overflow. (Of course.) `uint`? Bingo.

³ I've no idea if this solution is right for the wrong reasons. Or even worse. One thing that's concerning is that `uint` in Raku is defined to correspond to the largest native unsigned integer size supported by the Raku compiler used to compile the Raku code. (Iirc.) In practice today this means Rakudo and whatever underlying platform is being targeted, and I think that almost certainly means C's `uint64_t` in almost all cases. I imagine `perl` has some similar platform dependent definition. So my solution, if it is a reasonable one, is presumably only portable to the degree that the Raku compiler (which in practice today means Rakudo) agrees with the `perl` binary (which in practice today means P5P's `perl`) when run on some platform. See also @p6steve's comment below.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks. In fact the number IS a high 64-bit unsigned integer. Though it's a pity there isn't a direct coercion from Int to uint, because of that we can't do something like `say +^(18446744073709551592.uint)`

Comment: Condensed into a prefix op: `sub prefix:<^²>(uint $a) { (+^ $a) + 1 }; say ^² 18446744073709551592`  :-)

Comment: great answer! one comment IMO int8 / int16 / int32 and their unsigned brethen are here to stay and likely to get more important in high performance computing ... so the ideal example would be explicit on the word length

Comment: @p6steve To be clear I don't understand what's needed in this kind of thing, nor what's going on in my wild guess. (I just followed my nose, not my knows, got the right result, and posted.) Presumably you mean, if considering, for example, Liz's op (well, my variant of it, which I'm planning to add to my answer) , something like a family: `²^u64`, `²^i64`, `²^u32`, `²^i32`, etc.? So one could write `²^u64 18446744073709551592` for a two's complement unsigned 64 bit integer operation?

Comment: @raiph - yes, but (i) I would stick to the raku symbols uint64 not u64 and (ii) anyway I would be happy writing ```sub prefix:<²^>(uint64 $a) { (+^ $a) + 1 }``` when and where I needed it ;-)

Comment: reviewing this great answer again because I had forgotten it, and I hadn't integrated it into my almost throw away script 

Answer (score 2):

**'Long-hand' answer:**

```perl
raku -e 'put ( (18446744073709551592.base(2) - 0b1).comb.map({!$_.Int+0}).join.parse-base(2));'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'say 18446744073709551592.base(2).comb.map({!$_.Int+0}).join.parse-base(2) + 1;'
```

Sample Output: `24`

The answers above (should?) implement "Two's-Complement" encoding directly. Neither uses Raku's `+^` twos-complement operator. The first one subtracts one from the binary representation, then inverts. The second one inverts first, then adds one. Neither answer feels truly correct, yet the same answer as Perl5 is obtained (`24`).

Looking at the Raku Docs page, one would conclude that the "twos-complement" of a positive number would be negative, hence it's not clear what the Perl (and now Raku) answers represent. Hopefully the foregoing is somewhat useful.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/+$CIRCUMFLEX_ACCENT

Comment: Two's complement is a mechanism for storing negative numbers in binary, which works out to storing them modulo 2\*\*bits. In 8 bits, -1 has the same bit pattern as an unsigned 255, -2 as 254, and so on.

OP's giant number is the unsigned interpretation of the number -24 stored as a 64-bit value, aka 2\*\*64-24.

To get the representation of -N from +N or vice-versa, you flip all the bits and then add 1 - or subtract 1 and then flip; same answer either way. The two numbers are each the two's complement of the other, so this process is the operation sought here.